# Creating a fallback field to load conditionally

Tags: nodes

So if I have a node type of Article. I have two fields on it:

- field_image
- field_secondary

If field_secondary is being used, I'd like for that to be shown over field_image. Can anyone help point me in the right direction how I'd go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If field_secondary is also an image field, then you can check if it is empty in your Twig template:

For example, in `node--article.html.twig`:

```
{% if content.field_secondary is empty %}
  {{ content.field_image }}
{% else %}
  {{ content.field_secondary }}
  {{ content.field_image }}
{% endif %}

{{ content.without('field_image', 'field_secondary') }}
```

(Your actual template will have more HTML in it.)

Comment: Thanks so much! This looks like exactly what I need. I'm pretty new with Twig, and was thinking I'd have to write a custom helper function for all this.